# How to get postfix send mail (with Gmail smtp) under macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, launchd, smtp

I have tried everything (I guess), such as writing my sasl_passwd and editing main.cf in the `/etc/postfix` folder (as described in [1](https://www.justinsilver.com/technology/osx/send-emails-mac-os-x-postfix-gmail-relay/?unapproved=2688&moderation-hash=cf71581ee481cb1c6f76481946c2ef7e#comment-2684)).  I also copied my LaunchDaemon plist with a different name to my `/Library/LaunchDaemons` folder (as described in [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229331/how-to-modify-a-launch-daemon-permanently-under-os-x-el-capitan)).

While those people managed to get postfix to send smtp Gmail messages from their terminal under Mojave and El Capitan, respectively. I haven't managed to get their solutions to work under Catalina.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at https://gist.github.com/loziju/66d3f024e102704ff5222e54a4bfd50e
Some people stated it works for them.

Comment: link-only answers are discouraged as the link can go away or change to the point of making the link useless. Please summarize the solution **AND** provide the link in your answer.

Comment: @SteveChambers thank you for your opinion. All the information is consolidated and summarized there. That's why I provided the link. If you have a better solution (answer to the question) I would be thankful to you and glad to see it.
It is always easier to criticize than to create (c)

Comment: @SteveChambers is correct and it's not a criticism.  Links can and often go stale so if/when it does, this answer becomes useless.  The idea is to put the relevant point here so the user isn't required to leave this site to find the info.

Comment: No worries @iamtodor you don’t have to add more details. Anyone here can edit to summarize. No worries if a few downvotes rack up.  After edits this could be the start of an amazing answer